# Magnification glass doesn't come up anymore when moving text cursor?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, text-editor, cursor

When I type, say if I want to move the cursor to some position back to do the edit, I would hold the finger down and then it will display a magnification glass that was very handy to use to move the cursor into a new position.

But now for some reason that magnification glass doesn't come up. So to change something I have to literally erase the end of the sentence and type it again. Which is HELLUVA inconvenient!

What happened to that magnification glass? How do I get it back?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: @RyDev: v.13.1.3

Answer (score 1):

The magnifying glass is **back in iOS 15**.

> **Magnification loupe for text cursor and selection**
> Select exactly the text you want with an improved cursor that magnifies the text you’re looking at.

https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-15-preview/features/

---

The magnifying glass has been [**removed in iOS 13**](https://support.apple.com/HT210393#13).

> Text Editing
>
> - Faster and more precise cursor navigation—just pick it up and move it to where you want

You can find an overview of the new text editing tools in iOS 13 at https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph3c50f96e/ios

Comment: Oh, wow. I can't believe that there's no way to turn that garbage option off. It makes the keyboard quite unusable for me. Is there a way to revert back to the old version?

Comment: @c00 iOS 15 brings back a magnifying loupe.

Comment: Will iOS 16 remove it 